# Nokogiri and while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, while-loop, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse a XML with Nokogiri in my Rails Project.

This is my controller:

```
def landeplatz
    require 'nokogiri'
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/moredata.xml"))
    @links = doc.xpath('//markers/marker').map do |i| {
        'title' => i.attr('title'), 
        'desc' => i.attr('desc'),
        'email' => i.attr('email'),
        'website' => i.attr('website'),
        'address' => i.attr('address'),
        'type' => i.attr('type')
        }
    end
end
```

This is my view:

```
<% @links.each do |l| %>
    <% while l['type'] = 'bildung' %>
        <div class="span4 lande-item">
            <h4><%= l['title'] %></h4>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @links.each do |l| %>
    <% while l['type'] = 'wirtschaft' %>
        <div class="span4 lande-item">
            <h4><%= l['title'] %></h4>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
....
```

I don't see any of the items when I add the `while` loop.
Does anybody know where the problem is?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of xml too

Comment: while l['type'] = 'bildung', should be == (double equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One possibility is that your `@links` variable is an empty array. In this case, neither of your blocks will get evaluated.
2. Beware of `=` instead of `==` in your while loop condition. This would lead to an infinite loop as the assignment will always return a truthy value.
3. There are more idiomatic ways to perform what you want. For instance :

   ```
   <% @links.select{|link| 'bildung' == link['type']}.each do |link| %>
     <div class="span4 lande-item">
       <h4><%= link['title'] %></h4>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   ```

   or using `group_by` :

   ```
   <% @links.group_by{|link| link['type']}['bildung'].each do |link| %>
     <div class="span4 lande-item">
       <h4><%= link['title'] %></h4>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   ```

   there are many other ways, all using idiomatic ruby blocks. 
   In ruby many objects implement the `each` method and leverage the power of the [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) : learn how to use this module's methods and you will almost never have to use a while loop.

Comment: unfortunately, ruby doc is down today (gasp!) so the link to `Enumerable` won't work. here's another : http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful explaining! Now it works like a charm and  how it should work!